# If $(\tilde X, p)$ is a covering space of $X$ and $x_0 \in X$ then the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$ is a discrete subset of $\tilde X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> If $(\tilde X, p)$ is a covering space of $X$ and $x_0 \in X$, then the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$ is a discrete subset of $\tilde X$

I can see that by the definition of an open cover, there's an open neighborhood $U_{x_0}$ such that $p^{-1}(U_{x_0}) = \bigcup_{\text{disjoint}}S_i \text{ such that } S_i \in T_{\tilde X}$ and $p|_{S_i} : S_i \cong U_{x_0}$.

Since $x_0 \in U_{x_0}$ and $p|_{S_i} : S_i \cong U_{x_0}$, then it follows by composition that each $p^{-1}(x_0)$ should be a single point in each $S_i$.

But this doesn't show that it's discrete, because couldn't there be uncountably many $S_i$?

Am I missing something or is there a different way to show this?

Comment: "Discrete" here means that the induced topology on the fiber, as a subspace of $\widetilde{X}$, is the discrete topology. It is not related, a priori, to the cardinality of the fiber whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  So this means to show that if $A \subseteq p^{-1}(x_0) \Rightarrow A \in T_{p^{-1}(x_0)} \Rightarrow A \in \{p^{-1}(x_0) \cap O : O \in T_{\tilde X} \} \Rightarrow$ $A = p^{-1}(x_0) \cap O_A \text{ for some $O_A \in T_{\tilde X}$ }$.  

Which is simply found by just making  $O_A = \bigcup S_i$ such that each $S_i$ contains an element from $A$.   Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1):

A discrete set need not be countable, and also it does not matter that your proof has not addressed this point!

You may like to know that on second countable spaces, all discrete sets are necessarily countable. This includes objects such as real and complex manifolds and separable metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is a discrete subset of $\tilde X$ is equivalent for every $s\in S$, there exists an open subset $U_s$ of $\tilde X$ containing $s$ such that $U_s\cap U_{s'}$ is empty if $s\neq s'$, this does not implies that $S$ is countable.

You can endow any set with the discrete topology and it is the covering of the point.